# How do I make eclipse format my tml files like I want them to be?

Tags: xml, eclipse, tapestry, eclipse-juno

Using Eclipse Juno SR1:

I have [Tapestry Tools](http://code.google.com/p/tapestrytools/) installed in my eclipse installation, and I've customized my XML Formatter too.

However, regardless whether I open the tml file in the TML editor or the XML editor, when I let eclipse format the file, different formatting rules are used than for "normal" XML files.

How can I make sure the same rules apply?

Also, why does the formatter sometimes allow longer lines than the specified line width? it seems it only introduces a line break if an attribute is beyond the limit, but not if the attribute value is too long...

Referenced Questions:

[How to configure Eclipse XML formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943350/how-to-configure-eclipse-xml-formatting)

[Export the Eclipse XML Formatting Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424132/export-the-eclipse-xml-formatting-rules)

Comment: Your question seems somewhat unclear about what the problem really is, what you try to acheive and what you've tested so far.

Comment: maybe you could attach some screenshots of the problem. I am using eclipse and the tapestry tools as well, but can't figure out what you really mean.

Comment: I changed the XML Formatter to use space instead of tabs, and to use more width. TML-Formatting still applies tabs.

Comment: regarding the line length: it seems to me that the XML formatter does not enforce a strict line length but only introduces line breaks if an attribute="value" pair has the attribute beyond the limit, not if the value is too long.

Answer (score 3):

Make a *.tml act like a *.xml by doing this:

1. In the preferences, go to **General > Content Types**.
2. Under **Content types:** scroll down and expand `Text`.
3. Scroll down to `XML`.
4. For the **File Associations** click **Add** and put in `*.tml`.

Comment: *.tml is associated under Text > XML > TML - does the additional association help? It would still open in the TML editor, not the normal XML editor. I'd rather have a solution where I could use the TML editor